# I am very new to MySQL and don't know why there are dupliacte items being added to each row?

Tags: mysql

This is currently all that I have simply because I wanted to test adding items to a table, and making sure that said item wasn't a duplicate. I saw that if you add INSERT IGNORE that it supposedly stops the creation of duplicated items but in my case, that didn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testing (test0 TEXT, test10 TEXT);

INSERT IGNORE INTO testing VALUES ("TEST1","TEST2");
INSERT IGNORE INTO testing VALUES ("TEST1","TEST2");
INSERT IGNORE INTO testing VALUES ("TEST1","TEST2");
INSERT IGNORE INTO testing VALUES ("TEST1","TEST2");
INSERT IGNORE INTO testing VALUES ("TEST1","TEST2");
```

Comment: It’ s A duplicate on indexes, which you don’t have

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of `INSERT IGNORE`, is to not interrupt the execution of insert statements if one fails for any reason.
For example if you try to insert string value in a Integer column, it would just ignore the error and insert nothing then.

I think in your case you need to create a `UNIQUE` constraint for desired fields :)

Comment: After asking the question, I noticed that it doesn't even really apply to what I am trying to do, what I'm trying to do is in python and I can just check if the item already exists over there, and if it does then I will just skip it. When I asked the question I was thinking that I was stuck in MySQL for some reason. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT IGNORE`  just works in case of avoiding errors when you do the insert statement, it simply gonna let you insert the values because as I see there is not an identifier or   `PRIMARY KEY`  or   `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`   to identify each element as unique that key is the one who cannot be duplicate, the "test01" and "test10" are just normal data types.